# Can Safe AA hold any ERC20 token?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

So currently what i want to do is to make my Safe AA hold ERC20 not just native tokens which i can use this ERC20 to transfer to other wallets or even use to pay something on a Dapp. Is Safe AA capable on doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes your safe AA is capable of holding any type of tokens whether it be ERC-20 or NFT (both 721 and 1155). For now you can use ERC-20 tokens to pay for gas fees .